# Scanning for two word phrase in Python dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to use a Python dictionary object to help translate an input string to other words or phrases. I am having success with translating single words from the input, but I can't seem to figure out how to translate  multi-word phrases.

Example:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
myDict = {"hello": "hi","mean adult":"grumpy elder", ...ect}
```

How can I return `hi grumpy elder` if the user enters `hello mean adult` for the input?

Comment: It only works for single word phrases because I split the input into a list of words using the split() method. Then I process the list one element at a time until a match is found in myDict . Then i return the resulting value.

Comment: If you use `split` them please [edit] your question and add this code. But why are you splitting the input in the first place?

Comment: How are we supposed to decipher what should be a two word substring, three word substring .. or a single word substring, bruteforce every combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as you normally would.

```
translation = myDict['fast car']
```

A solution to your particular problem would be something like the following, where `maxlen` is the maximum number of words in a single phrase in the dictionary.

```
translation = []

words = sentence.split(' ')
maxlen = 3
index = 0

while index < len(words):
    for i in range(maxlen, 0, -1):
        phrase = ' '.join(words[index:index+i])
        if phrase in myDict:
            translation.append(myDict[phrase])
            index += i
            break
    else:
        translation.append(words[index])
        index += 1

print ' '.join(translation)
```

Given the sentence  `hello this is a nice fast car`, it outputs `hi this is a sweet quick ride`

Answer (score 2):

`"fast car"` is a key to the dictionary, so you can extract the value if you use the key coming back from it.

If you're taking the input *straight* from the user and using it to reference the dictionary, `get` is safer, as it allows you to provide a default value in case the key doesn't exist.

```
print(myDict.get(sentence, "Phrase not found"))
```

Since you've clarified your requirements a bit more, the hard part now is the splitting; the `get` doesn't change.  If you can guarantee the order and structure of the sentences (that is, it's always going to be structured such that we have a phrase with 1 word followed by a phrase with 2 words), then split only on the first occurrence of a space character.

```
split_input = input.split(' ', 1)
print("{} {}".format(myDict.get(split_input[0]), myDict.get(split_input[1])))
```

More complex split requirements I leave as an exercise for the reader.  A hint would be to use the keys of `myDict` to determine what valid tokens are present in the sentence.

Comment: But he wants to find multi word phrases in `sentence`, not use the whole sentence as the key.

Comment: "fast car" is, at best, a sentence fragment.  Further, it's also the key to access the data that they want, so why shouldn't they use it?  If they've got deeper concerns than what I've expressed here, then they should edit their question indicating such.

Comment: @chown is correct this is not what I needed. I edited the original question so hopefully it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

This will check for each word and also a two word phrase using the word before and after the current word to make the phrase:

```
myDict = {"hello": "hi",
          "fast car": "quick ride"}
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
words = sentence.split()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word in myDict:
        print myDict.get(word)
        continue
    if i:
        phrase = ' '.join([words[i-1], word])
        if phrase1 in myDict:
            print myDict.get(phrase)
            continue
    if i < len(words)-1:
        phrase = ' '.join([word, words[i+1])
        if phrase in myDict:
            print myDict.get(phrase)
            continue
```